# Power BI: add slicer value into table

Tags: powerbi, dax

My data model has one table, `Tbl`. It has a few fields including `F1`.

On my page, there is a slicer (filter) on `F1`. I want to build a measure that returns the filtered value for `F1` and add it to a table visual.

The visual would look as such:

```
F1 (all values) | F1 (filtered value)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: When you say `F1 (all values)`, are you expecting an aggregation, like a sum or average over all values, or something else?

Comment: @AlexisOlson let me clarify. Let's say F1 contains values: a,b and c. Let's say that on my page, I have a slicer on F1 filtering for value b. On the same page, I have a table visual. I want this table to display 2 fields: all the values for F1 and the filtered value. So it'd look like this: { F1 (all values) | F1 (filtered value) }, { a | b }, { b | b }, { c | b }. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky since you want the slicer to affect one column but not the other.

What I would do is create a new table to use in a slicer.

Modeling > New Table: `Slicer = VALUES(Table1[F1])`

Then use `Slicer[F1]` for you slicer instead of `Table1[Slicer]` and define a measure

```
Selected F1 = MAX(Slicer[F1])
```

(You can use a different function like `LASTNONBLANK`or `SELECTEDVALUE` instead of `MAX` if you prefer.)

Then if you set up your table with `Table1[F1]` and `[Selected F1]`, it should look like this:

[image: Slicer Selection]

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the measure that returns the filtered value Ms1.
If you want another measure that will not be impacted by the slicer and calculated on all Values of F1, then you will want to use the ALL function.
The new measure Ms2 would look like this :

Ms2 = Calculate([Ms1],ALL(Table[F1]))

Comment: I'm actually trying to build Ms1